# Batch set orientation of local axes on multyple objects?

Tags: scripting, origin, transform-orientation

I have a structure composed of many separeted cylenders (maybe later it will be more complexe mesh).

And the local axes orientation of each cylender is wrong (based on global).

I know how to set (reset) the orientation manually one by one on each cylenders

But I’m looking for a batch solution which will guess the best orientation for each cylenders.

Maybe based on the orientation of the longest edge ?

Or based on the normals of the caps ?

Or based on an average of the dimensions of the geometry (probably the best if the shapes are not consistent) ?

Do you know a script or an addon which can do that ?

I found these two addon which look great but still need to specify manually some informations, like edges or 3 points … (I would like to automate that).

https://blendermarket.com/products/set-origin-local-axes
https://blendermarket.com/products/fsaligntool

Thanks for your help !

[image: batch orientation of local axes]

Answer (score 0):

I see that a lot of objects have the same rotation. So that you can edit them at once. Make a transform orientation based on selected edge or face

[image]

Activate transform only origins:

[image]

Then select all objects with the same rotation and click Object → Transform → Align to transform rotation.

[image]

Comment: Hello Crantisz

Thanks for your answer.

Maybe it's not really visible In my example, but all cylinders have sightly different random rotations even the one which looks parallel.

I already know the manipulation you mentioned, but what about if I have a structure with one thousand cylinders all in different orientation?

That's why I'm looking and automated way to achieve that.